# Programmatically Pivoting the Google Visualization dataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable, google-visualization, pivot

I excited with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HkjDe/) and I tried to create the same kind with reference to that fiddle. My modified sample is given in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/) and i'm trying to create a view as follows.

```
var distinctValues = data.getDistinctValues(2);

    var viewColumns = [1];
    var groupColumns = [];
    // build column arrays for the view and grouping
    for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
        viewColumns.push({
            type: 'number',
            label: distinctValues[i],
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
        });
        groupColumns.push({
            column: i+1,
            type: 'number',
            //label: distinctValues[i],
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
        });
    }
```

But my aim is to create a pivot table something like as follows.

```
['Column1', 'Column2', 100, 200, 300, 400],
['A', 'bar', 0, 1, 1, 0],
['A', 'baz', 0, 0, 1, 0],
['A', 'foo', 3, 1, 0, 0],
['B', 'baz', 0, 1, 0, 0],
['B', 'cad', 1, 0, 1, 1],
['B', 'qud', 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change a few things in your code.  First, the viewColumns needs to contain both columns 0 and 1 to start if you want Column1 and Column2 to both be in the output.  Then, you need to adjust the columns you add to the viewColumns: each one needs a calc parameter which calculates the value in the column.  In this case, you want to compare the value of the column to distinctValues[i] and return 1 when they match and 0 when they don't.  In the aggregation function for groupColumns, use sum instead of count:

```
var distinctValues = data.getDistinctValues(2);

var viewColumns = [0, 1];
var groupColumns = [];
// build column arrays for the view and grouping
for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
    viewColumns.push({
        type: 'number',
        label: distinctValues[i],
        calc: (function (x) {
            return function (dt, row) {
                return (dt.getValue(row, 2) == x) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        })(distinctValues[i])
    });
    groupColumns.push({
        column: i+2,
        type: 'number',
        //label: distinctValues[i],
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    });
}
```

Then, in the grouping function, pass columns 0 and 1 in the first array:

var pivotedData = google.visualization.data.group(view, [0, 1], groupColumns);

See these changes working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DUn6B/1/

Comment: Can I set one more column in between `pivotData` array? ie, something like `['Column1', 'Column2', 100, 500, 200, 300, 400], ['A', 'bar', 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], ['A', 'baz', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['A', 'foo', 3, 1, 0, 0, 0], ['B', 'baz', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], ['B', 'cad', 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], ['B', 'qud', 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]` I managed to create [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/2/). But is there any better ways?

Comment: I also created [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/3/). Suggest me better ways if any.

Comment: Do you want your pivoted data to include columns with the headers 500 and 600, even when there is no data with those values?  The easiest way might be to build the `distinctValues` array manually, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DUn6B/4/

Comment: I modified my code as Ur suggestion and added the column `total` which is [fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/5/). For finding total, any other better methods?

Comment: You can add a "Total" column to your view and group columns: http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/6/