# Finding sub total and grand total

Tags: javascript, printing, google-visualization, subtotal

With reference to the answer given by Mr. asgallant for my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603487/programmatically-pivoting-the-google-visualization-datatable), I extended my sample like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/7/) where I added a column named "Total" and sum of each columns. Also I added a print button as,

```
function printPage(){
    var tableData = '<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4px" style="font-family: arial, helvetica; font-size: 10pt; border-spacing: 0;"><tr><td colspan="10">Print Report</td></tr>' +document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'<tr style="padding-bottom: 4px; width:100%; font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: arial, helvetica; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;"><td colspan="3">Total:&nbsp;</td><td>'+C100+'</td><td>'+C500+'</td><td>'+C200+'</td><td>'+C600+'</td><td>'+C300+'</td><td>'+C400+'</td><td>'+CTotal+'</td></tr></table>';
    var data = tableData+'<style type="text/css" media="print"> .noprint {visibility: hidden;} </style><br/><button class="noprint" onclick="window.print()" >Print the Report</button><button class="noprint" onclick="window.close();">Close Preview</button><br />';        
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.focus();
};
```

which given in the fiddle. But I am trying to achieve some format in print page as given below.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the Visualization API Tables don't support the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes you need to use to make that layout.

Comment: Is there any methods to find subtotal of `A` and `B` and its grand total without `rowspan` and `colspan` like [in this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WZk7r.png)

Comment: Yes, you can insert new rows to your DataTable that contain the "A" and "B" subtotals and the "Grand Total".  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DUn6B/9/

Comment: I am updated ur example [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/10/) where i added a category filter control. If I select `A`, how can I show only `A` with its sub total and grand total. Also How can I handle only `A` and `B` in category filter?

Comment: @asgallant - I managed to get the report with category filter as i asked in the above comment here: http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/11/. Thanks...

Comment: But the grand total is `A Total + B Total` value.

Comment: You just need to calculate the Grand Total before adding the subtotals in: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DUn6B/12/

Comment: Is there any methods to set that inserted rows to bold-font? I tried with `reportview.setProperty` and `reportview.setCell` inside the loop [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/DUn6B/14/). But no output. Anyways Thank you very much @asgallant. Please add it as a answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You need to set the "style" or "className" property of the cells you want to make bold (depending on whether you want to use inline styles or CSS classes).  I'll make a new fiddle and add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code to address the base question and comments:

```
function drawTable(response) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Column1');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Column2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Column3');
    data.addRows([
        ['A', 'foo', 100],
        ['A', 'foo', 200],
        ['A', 'foo', 100],
        ['A', 'foo', 100],
        ['A', 'bar', 200],
        ['A', 'bar', 300],
        ['A', 'baz', 300],
        ['B', 'baz', 200],
        ['B', 'cad', 300],
        ['B', 'cad', 400],
        ['B', 'cad', 100]
    ]);

    //  var distinctValues = data.getDistinctValues(2);
    var distinctValues = [100, 500, 200, 600, 300, 400];

    var viewColumns = [0, 1];
    var groupColumns = [];
    // build column arrays for the view and grouping
    for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
        viewColumns.push({
            type: 'number',
            label: distinctValues[i],
            calc: (function (x) {
                return function (dt, row) {
                    return (dt.getValue(row, 2) == x) ? 1 : 0;
                }
            })(distinctValues[i])
        });
        groupColumns.push({
            column: i+2,
            type: 'number',
            //label: distinctValues[i],
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
        });
    }

    //total column
    viewColumns.push({
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Total',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return 1;
        }
    });
    groupColumns.push({
        column: distinctValues.length + 2,
        type: 'number',
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    });

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    // next, we group the view on column A, which gets us the pivoted data
    var pivotedData = google.visualization.data.group(view, [0, 1], groupColumns);

    var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
        'containerId': 'control',
        'options': {
            'filterColumnIndex': 0,
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                'caption': 'Select',
                'allowTyping': false,
                'allowMultiple': false
            }
        }
    });

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'table1',
        'options': {
            'width': '100%',
            'showRowNumber' : true
        },
    });

    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    bind(control, table).
    // Configure & bind the controls 
    draw(pivotedData);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
        var reportview = google.visualization.data.group(table.getDataTable(), [0, 1], groupColumns);
        var subTotals = google.visualization.data.group(reportview, [0], groupColumns);

        var grandTotal = google.visualization.data.group(reportview, [{
            type: 'string',
            column: 0,
            modifier: function (val) {return null;}
        }], groupColumns);

        // add subtotals to pivotedData
        for (var i = reportview.getNumberOfRows() - 1, oldVal, newVal, row, subIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
            newVal = reportview.getValue(i, 0);
            if (oldVal != newVal) {
                oldVal = newVal;
                subIndex = subTotals.getFilteredRows([{column: 0, value: newVal}])[0];
                row = [{v: subTotals.getValue(subIndex, 0) + ' Total', p: {style: 'font-style:bold; font-size:22px;'}}, null];
                for (var j = 1; j < subTotals.getNumberOfColumns(); j++) {
                    row.push({v: subTotals.getValue(subIndex, j), p: {style: 'font-style:bold; font-size:22px;'}});
                }
                reportview.insertRows(i + 1, [row]);
            }
        }

        // add grand total to pivotedData
        var row = [{v: 'Grand Total', p: {style: 'font-style:bold; font-size:22px;'}}, null];
        for (var i = 1; i < grandTotal.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            row.push({v: grandTotal.getValue(0, i), p: {style: 'font-style:bold; font-size:22px;'}});
        }
        reportview.addRow(row);

        var table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table2'));
        table2.draw(reportview, {'width': '100%', 'showRowNumber' : true, allowHtml: true});
    });
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DUn6B/15/

Comment: Thank you. One more small thing. ie, how can I show only a single value if the same value is repeating? for eg., in the fiddle, how can i show only the value `A` in `column1` instead of three A's. I am studying with one of your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/qKWZT/ about it.

Comment: If you are looking to do something like column1 in the image in your post, that isn't supported by the API.  If you are willing to have a crude hack in your code, you can use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/DUn6B/16/.  As an aside, I would recommend disabling table sorting, as it will mess up your subtotal and grand total rows (set `sort: 'disable'` in the table options).