# sorting the distinct values of google visualization datatable

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatable, google-visualization

I created a [sample fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThBeK/) with the help of Mr. asgallant's answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603487/programmatically-pivoting-the-google-visualization-datatable). Here i am pivoting the data table as,

```
var distinctValues = data.getDistinctValues(3);

var viewColumns = [0, 1];
var groupColumns = [];
// build column arrays for the view and grouping
for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
    viewColumns.push({
        type: 'number',
        label: distinctValues[i],
        calc: (function (x) {
            return function (dt, row) {
                return (dt.getValue(row, 3) == x) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        })(distinctValues[i])
    });
    groupColumns.push({
        column: i+2,
        type: 'number',
        //label: distinctValues[i],
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    });
}
```

But if i using the `data.getDistinctValues(3);` method, the distinct values will sort in ascending order as `April, February, January, March`. So how can i disable sorting and i can get the order of columns as `January, February, March, April`?

Comment: You would have to manually re-sort them.  If your values are always going to be the same though (like a list of months), then you can hard-code that list: `var distinctValues = ['January', 'February', 'March'...];` instead of calculating it on the fly.

Comment: Yes... But month column should add dynamically based on data. So, if I hard-code it, the extra column will added with zero values even though a particular month is not present in the data table.

Comment: Or if I hard-code it, is there any technique to hide the month column with zero values? for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/ThBeK/2/

Comment: You can build an array containing just the months that are in the data set: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/ThBeK/3/

Comment: How can I handle this type of columns: http://jsfiddle.net/ThBeK/5/ ie, if `data.getDistinctValues(3)` have both month and year.

Comment: What would you like to have happen?

Comment: I am trying to order the column as `[Column1, Column2, January 2012, February 2012, March 2012, Total]`

Comment: I tweaked the code to sort by month and year, and made a test case with several years of data: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/ThBeK/6/